# How to detect the available part of the main display that's available for normal windows ?

Tags: java, desktop

On most desktop environments, you have one ore more action bars and sometimes docked windows.

A maximized window will used all the space that is not used by these different things on the side of the screen. That's what I'm calling the "available space"

Is there a java API to detect the available space, and if possible to listen to the changes that may occur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to get a reference to the screen device and subtract the screen insets from the screen bounds as follows

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

if (gd != null) {

    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
    bounds = gc.getBounds();

    Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);

    bounds.x += insets.left;
    bounds.y += insets.top;
    bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
    bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);

}
```

Now, your next problem is going to be to determine which screen device you actually want, this example simple uses the default screen ;)